# Rest API Docusign integration in production mode

Tags: node.js, rest, docusignapi, signature, private-key

Type of application : Authorization code grant embedded signing example

I'm using nodejs for requesting JWT User Token.
It's perfectly works on demo account.

When I use the live mode, I change User ID, API Account ID and Account Base URI to my live account.

Now I'm getting error : '{"error":"invalid_grant","error_description":"no_valid_keys_or_signatures"}'

How to make it works in live mode ?

Why the private key is not valide in live mode ?

Answer (score 0):

To get your app from demo/developer account to production you must go through the [go-live process](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/go-live/).

This process ensures your app is behaving well in the developer account before it is allowed to be in production (what you call "live").

To get this process going you have to approve your IK (Integration Key, like a clientId) and once this is done, you have to promote it, meaning you have to add it to a production account. Presumably you have a production account to use.

Beyond that I'm sending some confusing reading this:

> Type of application : Authorization code grant embedded signing
> example
>
> I'm using nodejs for requesting JWT User Token. It's perfectly works
> on demo account.

**Note** [JWT](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/jwt/) and [Authorization Code Grant](https://developers.docusign.com/platform/auth/authcode/) are two different authentication methods, you are probably using JWT, but I'm not 100% sure about that.

When you go-live you have to also create your RSA keypair (or your Auth Code Grant clientSecret) in the production env. You cannot use the same value from the developer account. Only the IK is promoted.

Comment: Thank you very much. I have new error : {"errorCode":"USER_DOES_NOT_BELONG_TO_SPECIFIED_ACCOUNT","message":"The specified User is not a member of the specified Account."}. I used account id from prodcution account.

Comment: That probably has to do with a mismatch of accounts/users between the developer and production accounts. If you are using JWT the userID is different and you have to update it as well.